# Transpose rows to columns using php

Tags: php

My html table looks like this :

[image]

I'm trying to transpose the values of the column `name_action` as follows :

[image]

I can't figure out an optimized algorithm to do so.

Update : so far i had a multidimensional array `results`that contained my data :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_demand] => 14
        [id_projet] => 81537
        [nom] => software_update
        [open_demand_date] => 09/12/10
        [close_date] => 06/04/11
        [name_action] => db_update
        [total] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_demand] => 14
        [id_projet] => 81537
        [nom] => software_update
        [open_demand_date] => 09/12/10
        [close_date] => 06/04/11
        [name_action] => closure
        [total] => 0
    )
```

another array `actions`contains the list of my actions.

```
Array
(
[0] => db_update
[1] => closure
[2] => validation
[3] => networking
[4] => os_creation
[5] => os_installation
```

)

the first idea i had is to 'draw' the html tab, then try to fill it :

```
foreach ($result[0] as $k=>$v){
        if ($k == 'name_action') break;
        else 
            echo "<th>".$k."</th>"; 
        }
    foreach ($actions as $k => $v){
        echo "<th>".$v."</th>";
    }
```

filling the target table required too much unnecessary looping.
Got a better idea from the comments (building a multidimensional array with `id_demand` as the key (thanks to Niet the Dark Absol)).

Comment: Provide more details. It's not clear what your data structure looks like.

Comment: I love how people who can't solve simple things always immediately look for "optimized" versions...

Comment: Optimised algorithm: iterate through your rows, build an array using `id_demand` as the key, if the key doesn't exist then create it with your row's data, and if it does then just add the current row's total in the appropriate action. Output new array as table. Done.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i appreciate your help. thanks.